# How to redirect the user back to the login page after logout in django/allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I installed a very basic project on django with the allauth module. It works well...except that i have a 404 page when i try to logout using  http://localhost:8000/accounts/logout/.

The urls.py

`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^aboutus/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="aboutus.html"), name="aboutus"),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]`

and in settings.py i set `ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET= True` to avoid the logout confirmation.

My goal is to set path: login page-->aboutus:click on logout button--> login page.

I read on internet a lot of stuff but it still does not work.

Please help

Comment: It looks like you can pass a parameter 'redirect_field_value' from the click action on the logout button to specify the redirect field!

Answer (score 16):

solution in the setting file : ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ="/accounts/login"

Comment: This seems to work, but I don't understand why it works. Is it functionality built into Allauth?

Comment: Yes @KimmoHintikka . That's why we place that in settings.py. plug & play

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, there is an answer for your question in official [docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects). Basically you just need to write your own adapter, it may look like:

```
# project/settings.py:
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'project.users.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'

# project/users/adapter.py:
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        path = "/accounts/{username}/"
        return path.format(username=request.user.username)
```

Comment: Thanks, i test with   I  get the error : No module named users.adapter

Comment: @alvaro562003, my code was just an example, it won't work with your project. You have to write your own adapter and set your app and project names. I add a link where you can find how to do this.

Comment: Yes, thank you, i adapted it basically i changed get_login_redirect_url into get_logout_redirect_url and i set ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'mysite users.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'.

Comment: many thanks pythad, after your advice i read the official doc and found the solution.